# i20 TPS sensor readings

Tags: throttle-position-sensor

my i20 1.2 petrol tps signal wire has .30 volt and other wire is 5 volt. However, my idle rpm is very2 low 600 rpm as against the normal 850 rpm.

Will adjusting to .45 volt brings the rpm to 850?? I have cleaned TB unit, air filter, sparks plug etc etc...but still low rpm 600 to 650. I want to bring up to at least 800 rpm.

Comment: This seems to be an unreliable car...

Comment: Yes you can adjust the TPS by turning it for a higher signal voltage. I think .3 volts is a little low. Do not adjust the screw that goes to the throttle linkage. Be sure the IAC is working right and check for any vacuum leaks before making any adjustments.

Comment: No vacuum leaks at all. IAC is working. But, I want to make the rpm to 800 from 600. So, will adjusting the said screws work?

Comment: Why affects will be on the engine if I adjusted the screws at the tps sensor??